# SQL - condtion in aggregate function while grouping

Tags: sql, postgresql

## table1

```
person    | zipcode     | timestamp               | event  | device
--------------------------------------------------|--------|------
amar      | 11111       | 2016-09-28 20:05:03.001 | email  | phone
akbar     | 11111       | 2016-09-28 20:05:03.001 | email  | phone  
antony    | 11111       | 2016-09-28 20:07:03.001 | chat   | pc
amar      | 11111       | 2016-09-28 20:08:03.001 | email  | phone
amar      | 11111       | 2016-09-28 20:08:03.001 | chat   | phone
amar      | 22222       | 2016-09-28 20:09:03.001 | email  | phone
akbar     | 22222       | 2016-09-28 20:10:03.001 | email  | phone  
antony    | 22222       | 2016-09-28 20:10:03.001 | chat   | phone
amar      | 11111       | 2016-09-28 21:05:03.001 | email  | phone
akbar     | 11111       | 2016-09-28 21:05:03.001 | email  | phone  
antony    | 11111       | 2016-09-28 21:07:03.001 | chat   | phone
```

**output desired**

```
 person    | total_events | email_events 
 ---------------------------------------
 amar       | 5           | 4
 akbar      | 3           | 3
 antony     | 3           | 0
```

Thinking of using `group by` for this like below - how to get count of events where `event = 'email'` here - is there a way to do this without using a sub-select?

```
select
  person
  , count (*) as total_events
from table1
group by person
```

Comment: `... count(*) filter (where event = 'email') as email_events`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `group by` along with `case`:

```
select person,
       count(*) as total_events,
       sum(case when event = 'email' then 1 else 0 end) as email_events
from table1
group by person;
```

In Postgres, you can shorten this to:

```
select person,
       count(*) as total_events,
       sum( (event = 'email')::int ) as email_events
from table1
group by person;
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the condition in `CASE` statement and wrap it in `COUNT` aggregate

Try this

```
select
  person
  , count (*) as total_events
  , Count(case when event = 'email' then 1 end) as email_events 
from table1
group by person
```

Comment: BTW simpler a bit: `..., count(nullif(event = 'email', false)) ...`